# Can you miss on purpose with Wormhole plunge?

Tags: dnd-4e, ardent

I want to cast [Wormhole plunge](http://dnd4.wikia.com/wiki/Wormhole_plunge) on an ally to teleport him away from enemies but I want to deal as little damage to him as possible. Can I miss on purpose to deal only half damage?

Comment: Worth noting you can't "take 10" in the hopes to fail, as you can only do so while not pressed or threatened.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope. If you target the ally, you roll against him like you would a monster. This is where it's handy to have a reroll or two in your pocket just in case you crit.

Some things you can do to decrease the odds:

- Use the power unarmed. This makes the power much less likely to hit (no magic weapon bonuses, no feat bonuses, no proficiency bonuses), and also does less damage (1d4 for unarmed, no magic item or feat bonuses).
- Close your eyes. This is a DM discretion thing, but it should grant total concealment which is a -5 to hit. The thing I would be worried about here is that you can't teleport something to a square you don't have LOS to. The DM's ruling on when your eyes open is a big deal here.

Note that the basic attack from your ally *is* optional so that does not have to take place.